# Filter an array of objects by an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter an array of objects by a dynamic object. Both of them are store in **state** using react hooks. My state looks like this:

```
const state = [
{
id : 1,
gender: "male",
category: "shirt",
brand: "firstBrand"
},
{
id : 2,
gender: "male",
category: "shirt"
brand: "secondBrand"
},
{
id : 3,
gender: "female",
category: "short"
brand: "firstBrand"
},

]
```

So as I said I need to filter the above array by an object that can be dynamic. What i mean by that is that Object is set ***onClick*** so it can filter what user want to see. for example if user click on *male* as a gender and *firstBrand* as a brand it will set my filter state like this:

> ```
> const filter = {
> gender: "male",
> brand: "firstBrand"
> }
> ```

Also I try a solution like this:

```
function Category  () {
    if (filter.brand) {
        const stuff = state.filter(item => {
            return item.gender.toLowerCase().match(filter.category.toLowerCase())
                && item.brand.toLowerCase().match(filter.brand.toLowerCase())
        })
        return stuff
    } else {
        const stuff = state.filter(item => {
            return item.gender.toLowerCase().match(filter.gender.toLowerCase())
        })
        return stuff
    }

}
```

But the problem with this solution is to set  multiple condition to check if (in this case) filter.gender exist. So what I finally want is return all items from **state** where **filter** *propertys* and *values* are equal without have to check if **filter.key** exist. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there is a more efficient way to do this, however this should work as a very generic way to filter all included properties:

- Loop through the properties on your filter object using `for (prop in object)`
- Filter the array of objects by each one as you go using `filter()`

```js
const data = [{
  id: 1,
  gender: "male",
  category: "shirt",
  brand: "firstBrand",
}, {
  id: 2,
  gender: "male",
  category: "shirt",
  brand: "secondBrand",
}, {
  id: 3,
  gender: "female",
  category: "short",
  brand: "firstBrand",
}]

function filterBy(filterObj) {
  // This syntax creates a new seperate copy of the data array
  let selectedData = [...data]
  // Loop through each property on the filter object
  for (const property in filterObj) {
    // For each property, filter the selected data to matching objects
    selectedData = selectedData.filter(o => o[property] === filterObj[property]);
  }
  // Use your filtered data
  console.log(selectedData)
}

// Examples:
console.log("Filter (male, firstBrand)")
filterBy({
  gender: "male",
  brand: "firstBrand"
})

console.log("Filter (firstBrand)")
filterBy({
  brand: "firstBrand"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compress this into a single `filter()` call with a nested `some()` called on the entries of the filter object. If `some()` of the entries don't match the source array, return false.

```
const filteredState = state.filter(o => (
  !Object.entries(filter).some(([k, v]) => (o[k] !== v))
  ));
```

```js
const state = [{id : 1,gender: "male",category: "shirt",brand: "firstBrand"},{id : 2,gender: "male",category: "shirt",brand: "secondBrand"},{id : 3,gender: "female",category: "short",brand: "firstBrand"}]

const filter = {
gender: "male",
brand: "firstBrand"
}

const filteredState = state.filter(o => {
  // if any of the filter entries don't match return false
  return !Object.entries(filter).some(([k, v]) => (o[k] !== v));
});

console.log(filteredState);
```

Or as a function...

```js
const state = [{id : 1,gender: "male",category: "shirt",brand: "firstBrand"},{id : 2,gender: "male",category: "shirt",brand: "secondBrand"},{id : 3,gender: "female",category: "short",brand: "firstBrand"}]

const filter = {
  gender: "male",
  brand: "firstBrand"
}

function filterArrayByObject(arr, filterObj) {
 return arr.filter(o => (
    !Object.entries(filterObj).some(([k, v]) => (o[k] !== v))
    ));
}

console.log(filterArrayByObject(state, filter));
console.log(filterArrayByObject(state, {category: 'shirt'}));
```