# How to write function that filters a dictionary when given a key/value pair in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter, include, key

I have a dictionary called teamData

```
var teamData = {
     app: {
      sortCol:"name",
      sortDir:"asc"
     },
     data: [
       {
         id: 1,
         name:"Raptors",
         coachId: 1,
         coachFirst: "Ken",
         coachLast: "jenson",
         coachPhone: "801-333-4444",
         coachEmail: "ken.jenson@uvu.edu",
         coachLicenseLevel: 1,
         league: 1,
         division: 1
       },
        {
         id: 2,
         name:"Killer Bunnies",
         coachId: 2,
         coachFirst: "Peter",
         coachLast: "Rabbit",
         coachPhone: "801-333-4444",
         coachEmail: "peter.rabbit@uvu.edu",
         coachLicenseLevel: 1,
         league: 1,
         division: 2
       },
       {
         id: 3,
         name:"Thunderbirds",
         coachId: 3,
         coachFirst: "Harry",
         coachLast: "DirtyDog",
         coachPhone: "801-333-4444",
         coachEmail: "harry.dirty.dog@uvu.edu",
         coachLicenseLevel: 2,
         league: 1,
         division: 2
       }
     ]
     
   }
```

I'm trying to write a function that takes a key/value object and returns a filtered dictionary. So if the function is

```
let teams = filter({coachLicenseLevel:1});
```

then the expected result is to return a filtered dictionary with only two elements that have that key/value pair

Here is the function I have so far, but I'm stuck on how to get the key object.

```
filter(filterObj) {
        const v = Object.values(filterObj);
        const k = Object.keys(filterObj);
        
        const res = teamData.filter(({???}) => v.includes(???));
    }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Dictionaries are called objects in JS. Do you really want to filter the whole object, or just the `data` array?  Please show the desired result.

Comment: You can't use `v.includes()` for this. Use the `some()` method to search for an element that matches a criteria. `includes()` can only be used for exact matches.

Comment: Do you want to apply it on the data array only?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020092/filter-an-array-of-objects-by-an-object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter only the data array, you could do  something like this:

```
 function filterArrayByParamAndValue(arr, itemParam, value) {
  return arr.filter(item => item.itemParam === value)

}
```

And in your code just replace the `data` property, if

```
let teamData = {
....,
data: [...filterArrayByParamAndValue(teamData.data, coachLicenseLevel, 1)],
....
}
```

Of course you should also add all necessary checks in the filter function, or even add an object property to check for and pass the whole object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing an object, you may consider using the filter function with your custom filter logic. Here is an example for your specific case:

```
let teams = teamData.data.filter(item => item.coachLicenseLevel == 1)
```